# Creation of Windows 10 install USB, no boot

Tags: ubuntu, boot, usb, windows-10

I just downloaded [the 64-bit Windows 10 ISO](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10ISO), and trying to create a pendrive installer (since my computer doesn't have an optical drive). The system I have available is Ubuntu 14.04, which is the same machine I'm trying to install Windows 10 to.

I tried every method listed in [an Ask Ubuntu question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/289559/how-can-i-create-a-windows-bootable-usb-stick-with-ubuntu), however the result is consistent: the drive is formatted properly, all files including the `bootx64.efi` file are correctly located, but it is not possible to boot to the USB stick.

When I restart the computer, press F8 during POST to select where to boot and pick the USB, the screen just flashes and goes back to the normal GRUB screen.

---

**Context:** I have a dual boot of Win7 + Ubuntu installed to different HDDs. The USB stick is a generic, 8GB USB 2.0.

**Specs:** AMD FX-6300, ASUS M5A97, 8GB RAM, a 500GB HDD (Win7) and a 1TB HDD (2 partitions, 300GB Ubuntu, 700 generic/shared with Windows)

Comment: Since you have Win 7, why not create the installer from [Rufus](http://rufus.akeo.ie/)?

Comment: @MartheenCahyaPaulo The Windows 7 install has been corrupted by Windows Update, and stuck on a reboot loop. Wouldn't bother with Win10 if not for that. :P

Comment: FYI in that case Win10 can't automatically activate with free upgrade scheme. You might better off repairing the Win 7 and upgrade from there.

Comment: @MartheenCahyaPaulo I know, but the Windows 7 install is FUBAR, would require a reinstall, and I don't have the CD anymore. I plan on installing the trial, then buying a key. Downloading W7 is out: considering the quality of my connection, the time cost invloved would surpass the cost of buying Windows 10.

Answer (score 1):

You can install Windows 10 from Ubuntu without even making a bootable USB. 
If you have the Windows 10 Setup ISO, extract all its contents to a separate partition, and then add a grub boot entry to boot from there.

First, Mount the ISO

> sudo mount -o loop [ISO_Path] [Mount_Point]

Copy its content to any other partition. Remember don't extract it into a Folder, just put all in the root of the drive(like D:\ or E:). Windows can not see **ext3/4** filesystem, so put it either in a **NTFS** or **Fat16/32** partition.

Now add a new menuentry in **/boot/grub/grub.cfg**

```
menuentry 'Windows 10' {
set root=(hdX,Y)
insmod part_msdos
insmod ntfs
insmod ntldr
drivemap -s (hd0) ${root}
ntldr /bootmgr
}
```

Here **(hdX,Y)** is the source where you have extracted the ISO image. Now restart your computer and select **Windows 10** from boot menu to continue installation.

Watch This On Youtube -> https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1Y4JXv9r5Ug